# Last record not saved into repo while doing bulk save operation

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, transactions

I got a very strange issue. I get data from UI and save the details in DB. Same time I also update current status in the DB. User can take actions in bulk as well. But in bulk operation (say 5 or 10 records), last record is not saved into one repo, while all the records are saved without any issue in another repo (service3).

I put some logs and checked. The entity in repo1 is saved with correct value, but it seems then the transaction rolled back. This happens only for the last record. So if you run 12 records, it will happen for 12th record. If you run 3 records, it will happen for 3rd record.

There is no exception thrown. The following is my class/method structure. Is the problem with `@Transactional` use?

```java
// service class 1
@Transactional    
saveAction(List<String> Actions) {
    forEach(action -> {
        doSomeOperation1();
        saveDetails();
        doSomeOperation2();
    });
}
```

```java
// Service class 2 (last record not saved in repo1)
    
@Transactional
saveDetails() {
    CustomerEntity customerEntity = CustomerEntity.builder.build();
    updateStatus();  //method in service class 3

    customerEntity.setSomeData("TEST");
    repo1.save(customerEntity);
}

// service class 3 (Details saved perfectly fine)

@Transactional
updateStatus() {
    StatusEntity statusEntity = StatusEntity.builder.build();
    repo2.save(statusEntity)
};
```

Is there a different way I can achieve the above without this inconsistency?

Comment: Please let me know in comments if the question is not clear.

Comment: do you have the same behaviour when you annotate saveAction @Transactional?

Comment: I haven't tried that. I will try and let you know.

Comment: @tremendous7 Sorry, Transactional was already there in the saveAction. I have edited it now.

Comment: I put some logs and checked. The entity in repo1 is saved with correct value, but it seems then the transaction rolled back. This happens only for the last record. So if you run 12 records, it will happen for 12th record. If you run 3 records, it will happen for 3rd record.